# Access an element of a function from within another function when not allow to use global variables(<<-)

Tags: r

```
b <- function() {
    x = 10
}

c <- function() {
    d = b()
    print(x)
}
```

How can I access element "x" when I am not allow to use global variables(<<-)

Comment: You already are basically accessing the value of `x`, because this is the return value from your `b()` function.  It could be considered bad encapsulation practice for the `c()` function have to know the inner workings of the `b()` function.  You should stick with what you have right now.

Answer (score 4):

Your function `b` returns the value `10`. Your function `c` runs `d = b()`, so it assigns the return value of `b` to a new object named `d`. This is good! You don't want your `c` function to have to know that the name `x` was used internally inside the `b` definition - you just supplied a new name `d`!

Change `print(x)` to `print(d)` and you are done.

As a side note, don't use `c` as a name for a custom function. There already is a function named `c`, and it's one of the most common functions used. Creating your own `c()` will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your example isn't truly reflective of what you want, it's possible that you're wanting to return the existing value of what b is really calculating, along with the x value.  You could return a list, which could contain both the original return value, and also the value of x

```
b <- function() {
x=10
...
list(x=x, previous=whatever_it_previously_returned)
}
```

Or you could also look at closures, but you'd need to give a more precise explanation of what you're trying to achieve, and where you want to have access to `x`.

Comment: Or even better, return `x` as an attribute of the return value.  The `structure()` function makes this easy.